# How do I enable the Japanese keyboard on the iPhone simulator?

Tags: ios, internationalization, keyboard, simulator, ime

I have a UITableview with a UISearchBar, which contain Japanese words, and I want to test if it works to search Japanese words with Japanese keyboard. I can't find how to change the default keyboard on iPhone simulator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open on simulator  **Settings** application **->General->International->Language**. Select here your language and keyboard will have required letters.

Comment: I see only ´reset content and settings´, no settings or general or anything like that..

Comment: I can understand Japanese, post a scr.

Comment: **Settings** is app into iphone simulator. Like Photos, Contacts, Safari.

Comment: Oh, I meant iPhone Simulator on Mac, not on my iPhone itself. Is it possible to simulate Japanese keyboard on iPhone simulator on Mac?

Comment: Just go to Settings, then click on 一般, and then　言語環境, and then　言語 and change to English or whatever language you use. And then click on 完了 :)

Comment: To reset the simulator from any language back to you home language use pattern recognition. Find the Settings picture and tap it, Find the smaller settings picture on the left and tap it, then click fourth row from bottom on the right column (that's International), click first row on next screen (that's Language), Look for your home language (it will always be in your language), and tap button in upper right to switch.

Answer (score 5):

I think what we really want to do is add an international keyboard, not change the language of the simulator.

1. Open Simulator
2. Find Settings. It's an app, not a menu item. Look for the icon with three gears.
3. Navigate to **General** > **Keyboard** > **International Keyboards** > **Add New Keyboard**
4. Now select the international keyboard(s) you'd like to add.
5. You can access the new keyboard(s) in your app by clicking the button that looks like a globe.
   [image]
6. Once selected, that keyboard will remain the default until you change it again using the method from step 5.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for Japanese (and Chinese) the keyboard layout isn't that important; what is needed is an input module converting the input to actual ideographic characters. Those are called "IME" (Input Method Editor)

A keyboard has just about a hundred keys, only half of them being alphabetic; but Japanese and Chinese need several thousands different characters. The role of IMEs are to convert phonetic of descriptive input into the wanted characters.
Japanese keyboard provides direct typing of phonetic japanese characters (katakana and hiragana); but all japanese IMEs acccept phonetic input either in native kana or in romanized (in latin letters).