# Xcode Simulator ignoring OS X keyboard layout

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, dvorak

I have the keyboard layout set to "Dvorak", but the simulator seems to assume "Qwerty" regardless. In the menus of "Hardware" > "Keyboard" I have checked off "Use the Same Keyboard Language as macOS" and "Connect Hardware Keyboard".  Is there a hidden secret option to *actually* use the macOS keyboard layout or is this just broken?  The wording seems to confound "language" with "layout".

I've seen a similar issue reported as a bug in iOS 8.2 simulator, but the simulator is reporting using iOS 11.2.  I'm running Xcode 9.2 and Simulator 10.0 .

**EDIT:**  I updated to the latest macOS (10.14.2) and latest Xcode (10.1) and the issue is still exactly the same.  I type in the simulator "aoeu" and I get "asdf".

Comment: on iOS simulator 12.1 not having the issue without any modifications, maybe try to update ?

Comment: @Mosbah - I'm using the latest version available on macOS Sierra so I guess I need to update the OS to Mojave and then update Xcode (I thought the OS update cost money, but apparently not).

Comment: @Mosbah - after a very long time I've managed to update macOS and Xcode and the issue still remains

Comment: Ah sorry for that, did you have the same with other layouts let's say french for example ?

Comment: @Mosbah - well, I need to do the update, any way...  :)  When I switch it to French/Azerty it seems to only work if I do an "Erase All Content and Settings...".  I then switched it back to Dvorak and tried a reset, but it just goes into Qwerty.  Looking in the settings, it appears iPhone has no built in support or Dvorak, so I guess that's the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS Simulator typing in Dvorak keyboard appears as QWERTY keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19223073/ios-simulator-typing-in-dvorak-keyboard-appears-as-qwerty-keys)

Answer (score 0):

In order to get Dvorak on the "external" keyboard it has to be manually selected in the settings by going to Settings > General > Keyboard > Hardware Keyboard > "English (United States)" and then selecting "Dvorak".  Of course, it just gets reset back to Qwerty after a reset.

Basically the "Use the Same Keyboard Language as macOS" is broken for Dvorak.  It may be due to it not being a setting in the software keyboard.