# Where is the iOS 7 simulator Japanese keyboard dictionary located?

Tags: ios7, ios-simulator, xcode5, simulator, multilingual

this question is a bit similar to this one.

[How do I enable the Japanese keyboard on the iPhone simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051141/how-do-i-enable-the-japanese-keyboard-on-the-iphone-simulator)

I get it to worked in Xcode 4.6, iOS Simulator 6. Things go all well. But when I upgraded to Xcode 5, iOS Simulator 7, the dictionary is gone... I can't write kanji, or even kana... where has the dictionary gone?

How do I make it work in the iOS Simulator (because I don't have the real device) like back there?

Edit Note: Ok, don't get it wrong. I changed the keyboard to japanese. Since I tap on japanese characters, normally a suggestion kanji/kana will pop-up in the suggestion area. But with the dictionary gone, it doesn't have any words on the suggestion area. Therefore, I can't write kanji...

I tried delete Xcode 5, re-install Xcode 4, things goes well. Upgrade back to Xcode 5 (duplicated app with Xcode 4), iOS sim 6 still work fine with dict., but iOS 7 doesn't. What is with Xcode 5 and iOS 7?

Edit Note 2: I think it got something to do with

> ~/Library/Application Support/Iphone Simulator/7.0/

But I'm not sure what... I tried copy the keyboard bundle from 6.1 to 7.0, still not solve the problem...

Edit note 3: I asked google for a while, but can't find any English document about this problem. Maybe it's best to ask in Japanese, but I don't know much about Japanese :( This is requirement for my current project :(

Edit note 4: To make it clear, I'll post the screenshot of before and after:

Before:
[image: Normally]

Now:
[image: Current state]

Edit note 5: Chinese dictionary still works fine. Maybe I did something wrong...? How to fix this?

Edit note 6: It seems there's some problems with the built-in keyboard dictionary... Maybe it's me, maybe Xcode 5, delete the dictionary features... Somehow, I can't restore it even with re-install. It seems I need something like... reset keyboard dictionary function, as on the terminal. It doesn't available on the simulator, right? Any idea?

P/s: I'm also sorry if my English is bad. I tried to write as simple as possible, but not very proper... Since I'm bad at English's grammar.

Comment: Did the solution below work for you?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, it's weekend :) As you see, the dictionary didn't return any phrases, suggestions... I think my dictionary feature got a problem, but I don't know how to fix it... Even re-install xcode doesn't help, and it cause xcode4.6 dictionary gone mad too.... Do you know anything about the built-in dictionary?

Comment: If you are having problems with the simulator dictionary you could visit this site for help reinstalling the simulator dictionary (http://support.apple.com/kb/TS5238).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to wait a bit for Apple to fix the bug. New simulators work pretty good!!

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

The Japanese Keyboard Dictionary is still available as part of the iOS simulator. There are two (2) ways to enable Japanese support.

*(either one of these methods will work)*

- General > Keyboard > Keyboards > Add New Keyboard... (Select Japanese
  Kana, Repeat this process to enable Japanese Romaji)

OR

- General > International > Keyboards > Add New Keyboard...(Select Japanese
  Kana, Repeat this process to enable Japanese Romaji)

**Japanese Kana Keyboard (iOS7)**
This appears to work normally.

To test:

- Verify that you are using latest version of Xcode (5.0.1)
- From Xcode menu select: Xcode > Open Developer Tool > iOS Simulator
- From iOS Simulator menu select: Hardware > Device > iPad > iOS 7.0.3
  (11B508)

[image: simulator menu]

- In iOS Simulator: Navigate to Settings > iCloud > Apple ID
- When Keyboard appears, click globe until keyboard list is shown and
  select Kana keyboard

[image: Kana]

**Japanese Romaji Keyboard (iOS7)**

Notice that the spacebar on Romaji keyboard has no Japanese Characters. However when one begins to type a Japanese phrase then the Japanese characters appear and the Japanese dictionary does return characters.

*Romaji Shows English Letters*
[image: Romaji]
*Begin Typing Japanese Sound with English Characters* 
[image: beginning]
Continuing to type out the Japanese sound in English Characters
*(Japanese word suggestions are shown)*
[image: continuing]
*Eventually Only Japanese suggestions appear in the top bar*
[image: finally]
*Extended suggestions are found by clicking the **up arrow in the right hand corner***
[image: Extended]

**Accessing the Japanese Keyboards**
*(click on background and drag mouse downward to show keyboard)*

One can access the Japanese Keyboards by clicking on the Springboard of the iPad simulator and dragging downward. The last used keyboard will appear. One can change keyboards by clicking the globe on the lower left.

[image: click+drag downward to show keyboard]

Note - Chinese and other international keyboards work in a similar way. The dictionaries are built into the latest version of Xcode. For more information on keyboards one can view the [Text Programming Guide, Managing Keyboards](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW2) section.

Comment: Thanks... it seems I deleted dictionary features by accident... Now, I can't even get it to work... Or maybe xcode5 is different from xcode5.0.1? I don't know how or why I managed to delete the dictionary feature... Do you know anything about it?

Comment: @Eddie You might try resetting the simulator or just reinstall the latest version of Xcode (5.0.1). The dictionary appears to work on my machine.